# How to see download count of an Android app on Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I cannot see the download counts of one app on Google Play.

How can we know that number of one app?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an end user, there is no way to know the exact number of downloads. But you can see a range if you scroll down the app page and look at the **Installs** section within **Additional Information**.

[image: Install count]