# How can I know the exact number of downloads for an app on Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I need to know the exact number of downloads (count, not range) for my app hosted on Google Play Store, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see download count of an Android app on Google Play store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87472/how-to-see-download-count-of-an-android-app-on-google-play-store). If you want to ask development-related question (i.e. using API), then [so] *might* be the correct site, but as of current writing, it's off-topic to ask for 3rd-party library recommendation.

Comment: The duplicate explains what the options for an end-user are, but note that questions about publishing to the Play Store or otherwise using it in a development capacity are outside our scope.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a number of downloads, you need to login to Google Play Developer Console. All information is there.