# What is the meaning of 1,000,000-5,000,000 installs in google play?

Tags: google-play-store

I used to see a number in Google Play Store app on my tablet showing the number of installs for an app. However, when opening google play in PC browser, e.g. for the [DI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audioaddict.di&hl=en) app (shown in figure) under "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION" section of the app page, it reads Installs: 1,000,000-5,000,000. What does this number show? If this is a range, how can it signify number of app installs?

[image]

Comment: It is a range as you state. And I don't think you can find a specific number.

Comment: It shows the total number of downloads for that app. Related/dupe question asked. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87472/how-to-see-download-count-of-an-android-app-on-google-play-store

Comment: So, how why this much difference? 4,000,000 difference!!! Doesn't google manage to give a more accurate install statistic?

Comment: Accurate download statistics is available to the developer of that app in the developer account dashboard. [Dashboard sample](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-db332a81ef911cdd711bc56e1aa89fc2)

Answer (score 3):

As you said, it is a *range*. That being so, it cannot signify the number of installs.

- Those getting *revenue* out of it- *developer and Google* need to know the exact number. Exact figures would be available with them.Thanks to Lucky for [confirming](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137417/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-000-000-5-000-000-installs-in-google-play#comment174802_137417)
- From a user perspective, I am not sure how exact number helps unless that metric is used to evaluate merit of the product! Which is not the use case for most

There is a source, which claims to provide you a view of the downloads and revenue figures, [Sensor Tower](https://sensortower.com/) (I have no idea how reliable it is- you could cross check with a developer). Website says:

> Sensor Tower is the leading app analytics platform focused on helping companies with mobile apps understand and improve their organic user acquisition, analyze their app’s performance, keep up to date with competitors and manage reviews. Over 90,000 mobile companies and developers use Sensor Tower to improve their downloads on iOS (iPhone, iPad and iPod) and Android

App mentioned has this statistic using the above source

[image]